# Problem with the simulation of two different low-pass filters

Tags: ltspice, low-pass

I am trying to simulate the circuit below. Why do both low-pass filters show the same behaviour, even though their component values are different?

[image: Circuit]

[image: Output]

[image: Input]

Edit: How stupid of me. I used the label **"In"** for the both circuit. That is the why I got same result.

Comment: *When I am simulating them seperatly (on each circuit file) they are filtering as expected.* - that's good so, what do you mean when you say this: *Why is that so? And how can I avoid it?* - what is it you're trying to avoid and what specifically do you need explaining? Also, what do you mean when you say this *Both low pass filters have the same behaviour* - clearly they shouldn't else why is one set to be 10 kHz and the other is 100 Hz?

Comment: having something work the first time around has shattered their world view

Comment: These are 100 Hz and 10 kHz LPFs. So why simulate up to 10 GHz??? I would say that up to 10 MHz is more than enough, then you should already see -60 dB on the 10 kHz filter. That would make it more easy to determine the -3dB point.

Comment: Do yourself a favour and edit the colours of the labels to be red, not the simulation cards. The labels are far, far more important.

Comment: You are definitly right. That's a good idea. @aconcernedcitizen

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that you'll find that this is "a" definite problem: -

[image]